# How to exclude Null values in output within $project

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the below $project pipleline within aggregation

```
 $project:
       {
        Difference:{{$subtract:["$ADate", "$QDate"]}}
```

However since my dataset is quite large, it outputs several NULL values, I am trying to exclude all NULL values from my ouput, I have tried using `$ne` but I continue to get errors.

Comment: dont want a replacement, i just want to exclude rows with null in Difference from the output

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles upon this problem in the future, this is what I used as my answer:

```
{$match:{Difference:{"$exists": true, "$ne":null}}},
```

Needed another `$match` stage after my `$project` stage specified above.